# How to understand and debug USB issues with Linux

Tags: linux, usb, drivers, kernel

I’m having an odd problem with a cheap "reverse USB hub"—I am not sure what the technical name might be— named a [Tek Republic TUS-200 USB Sharing Switch](http://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B00FEM3OKM/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1). It has one USB port for devices, and two host ports that I can connect two computers and then a switch that connects the device to one computer or another. I use it as a [KVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch) with one USB keyboard and two computers).

It works fine on Windows, but that may just be because the laptop I’m using has one USB bus per port... more on that later.

On Linux, [Debian 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_7_(Wheezy)) (Wheezy) 3.2.0-4-amd64, it works fine, until there is a considerable data transfer on another device on the same USB bus. For example, copying a large file to a pen drive.

I’m almost sure it has to do with grounding on the reverse-USB, because that does not happen when it is connected to only one computer.

But the question here is not so much to debug said device, but to **make sense** of the Linux kernel USB system log messages, as I never had to deal with them, and now I could not find absolutely nothing explaining it in layman terms.

Here it is: As soon as I start to transfer to a pen drive on the same USB bus that the reverse-hub is, I get this on [dmesg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmesg):

```
Feb  8 16:36:51 dotmatrix kernel: [10807.868649] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0006: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input1, status -75
Feb  8 16:36:51 dotmatrix kernel: [10807.872669] usb 1-1.6: clear tt 1 (00a0) error -71
Feb  8 16:36:51 dotmatrix kernel: [10807.873710] generic-usb 0003:04D9:A09F.0001: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.1/input0, status -71
Feb  8 16:36:51 dotmatrix kernel: [10807.876699] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0008: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input3, status -71
Feb  8 16:36:51 dotmatrix kernel: [10807.877658] usb 1-1.6: clear tt 1 (0080) error -71
Feb  8 16:36:51 dotmatrix kernel: [10807.881663] generic-usb 0003:04D9:A09F.0002: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.1/input1, status -71
Feb  8 16:36:51 dotmatrix kernel: [10807.881766] usb 1-1.6: clear tt 1 (00a0) error -71
Feb  8 16:36:51 dotmatrix kernel: [10807.883641] generic-usb 0003:0C45:7401.0004: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.3/input0, status -71
Feb  8 16:36:51 dotmatrix kernel: [10807.885815] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0006: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input1, status -71
Feb  8 16:36:51 dotmatrix kernel: [10807.885880] usb 1-1.6: clear tt 1 (0080) error -71
```

After a while, the messages become:

```
Feb  8 16:36:52 dotmatrix kernel: [10808.890502] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0008: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input3, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:52 dotmatrix kernel: [10808.890752] generic-usb 0003:04D9:A09F.0001: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.1/input0, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:52 dotmatrix kernel: [10808.892162] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0005: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input0, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:52 dotmatrix kernel: [10808.893202] generic-usb 0003:0C45:7401.0004: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.3/input0, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:52 dotmatrix kernel: [10808.894235] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0006: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input1, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:52 dotmatrix kernel: [10808.895038] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0008: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input3, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:52 dotmatrix kernel: [10808.898724] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0008: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input3, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:52 dotmatrix kernel: [10808.900590] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0008: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input3, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:52 dotmatrix kernel: [10808.901409] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0005: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input0, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:52 dotmatrix kernel: [10808.901668] generic-usb 0003:0C45:7401.0004: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.3/input0, status -32
```

And then a single:

```
Feb  8 16:36:57 dotmatrix kernel: [10814.370566] usb 1-1.6.1: device not accepting address 8, error -32
```

And then back to the status -32 as above. Sometimes it will 'reset':

```
Feb  8 16:36:58 dotmatrix kernel: [10815.142955] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0008: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input3, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:58 dotmatrix kernel: [10815.144945] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0008: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input3, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:58 dotmatrix kernel: [10815.288169] usb 1-1.6.1: reset full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci_hcd
Feb  8 16:36:58 dotmatrix kernel: [10815.438083] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0005: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input0, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:58 dotmatrix kernel: [10815.452998] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0005: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input0, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:58 dotmatrix kernel: [10815.467998] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0005: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input0, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:58 dotmatrix kernel: [10815.481784] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0005: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input0, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:58 dotmatrix kernel: [10815.508875] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0005: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input0, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:58 dotmatrix kernel: [10815.521838] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0005: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input0, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:58 dotmatrix kernel: [10815.533804] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0005: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input0, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:58 dotmatrix kernel: [10815.545770] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0005: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input0, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:58 dotmatrix kernel: [10815.557731] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0005: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input0, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:58 dotmatrix kernel: [10815.569698] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0005: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input0, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:58 dotmatrix kernel: [10815.603594] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0005: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input0, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:59 dotmatrix kernel: [10815.635501] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0005: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input0, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:59 dotmatrix kernel: [10815.656441] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0005: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input0, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:59 dotmatrix kernel: [10815.666411] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0005: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input0, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:59 dotmatrix kernel: [10815.666655] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0008: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input3, status -32
Feb  8 16:36:59 dotmatrix kernel: [10815.694672] usb 1-1.6.1: device not accepting address 8, error -32
Feb  8 16:36:59 dotmatrix kernel: [10815.696707] usb 1-1.6.1: USB disconnect, device number 8
Feb  8 16:36:59 dotmatrix kernel: [10815.954352] usb 1-1.6.3: reset low-speed USB device number 9 using ehci_hcd
Feb  8 16:36:59 dotmatrix kernel: [10816.213579] usb 1-1.6.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
Feb  8 16:36:59 dotmatrix kernel: [10816.576510] usb 1-1.6.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
Feb  8 16:37:00 dotmatrix kernel: [10816.683747] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0008: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input3, status -16
Feb  8 16:37:00 dotmatrix kernel: [10816.939302] usb 1-1.6.3: reset low-speed USB device number 9 using ehci_hcd
Feb  8 16:37:00 dotmatrix kernel: [10817.198547] usb 1-1.6.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
Feb  8 16:37:01 dotmatrix kernel: [10818.375220] usb 1-1.6.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
Feb  8 16:37:05 dotmatrix kernel: [10821.729353] usb 1-1.6.3: reset low-speed USB device number 9 using ehci_hcd
Feb  8 16:37:05 dotmatrix kernel: [10822.135753] usb 1-1.6.3: device not accepting address 9, error -32
Feb  8 16:37:06 dotmatrix kernel: [10823.392464] usb 1-1.6.3: reset low-speed USB device number 9 using ehci_hcd
Feb  8 16:37:07 dotmatrix kernel: [10823.798897] usb 1-1.6.3: device not accepting address 9, error -32
Feb  8 16:37:07 dotmatrix kernel: [10823.871064] usb 1-1.6.4: reset full-speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
Feb  8 16:37:08 dotmatrix kernel: [10825.031645] usb 1-1.6.1: new full-speed USB device number 19 using ehci_hcd
Feb  8 16:37:08 dotmatrix kernel: [10825.509849] usb 1-1.6.1: device not accepting address 19, error -32
Feb  8 16:37:09 dotmatrix kernel: [10826.427537] usb 1-1.6.1: new full-speed USB device number 20 using ehci_hcd
Feb  8 16:37:09 dotmatrix kernel: [10826.524335] usb 1-1.6.1: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
Feb  8 16:37:09 dotmatrix kernel: [10826.524340] usb 1-1.6.1: can't read configurations, error -32
Feb  8 16:37:10 dotmatrix kernel: [10826.595014] usb 1-1.6.1: new full-speed USB device number 21 using ehci_hcd
Feb  8 16:37:10 dotmatrix kernel: [10826.832449] usb 1-1.6.1: New USB device found, idVendor=04d9, idProduct=a09f
Feb  8 16:37:10 dotmatrix kernel: [10826.832454] usb 1-1.6.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Feb  8 16:37:10 dotmatrix kernel: [10826.832457] usb 1-1.6.1: Product: USB Gaming Mouse
Feb  8 16:37:10 dotmatrix kernel: [10826.832459] usb 1-1.6.1: Manufacturer: E-Signal
Feb  8 16:37:10 dotmatrix kernel: [10826.835328] input: E-Signal USB Gaming Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6.1/1-1.6.1:1.0/input/input11
Feb  8 16:37:10 dotmatrix kernel: [10826.835552] generic-usb 0003:04D9:A09F.0009: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [E-Signal USB Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6.1/input0
Feb  8 16:37:10 dotmatrix kernel: [10826.840323] input: E-Signal USB Gaming Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6.1/1-1.6.1:1.1/input/input12
Feb  8 16:37:10 dotmatrix kernel: [10826.840663] generic-usb 0003:04D9:A09F.000A: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [E-Signal USB Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6.1/input1
Feb  8 16:37:10 dotmatrix kernel: [10826.843392] generic-usb 0003:04D9:A09F.000B: hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [E-Signal USB Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6.1/input2
Feb  8 16:37:10 dotmatrix kernel: [10826.844372] usb 1-1.6.3: USB disconnect, device number 9
Feb  8 16:37:10 dotmatrix kernel: [10827.057683] usb 1-1.6.3: new low-speed USB device number 22 using ehci_hcd
Feb  8 16:37:10 dotmatrix kernel: [10827.129474] usb 1-1.6.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
Feb  8 16:37:10 dotmatrix kernel: [10827.304942] usb 1-1.6.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
Feb  8 16:37:10 dotmatrix kernel: [10827.480417] usb 1-1.6.3: new low-speed USB device number 23 using ehci_hcd
Feb  8 16:37:10 dotmatrix kernel: [10827.552202] usb 1-1.6.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
Feb  8 16:37:11 dotmatrix kernel: [10827.727689] usb 1-1.6.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
Feb  8 16:37:11 dotmatrix kernel: [10827.903169] usb 1-1.6.3: new low-speed USB device number 24 using ehci_hcd
Feb  8 16:37:11 dotmatrix kernel: [10828.029940] generic-usb 0003:04D9:A09F.000A: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.1/input1, status -32
Feb  8 16:37:11 dotmatrix kernel: [10828.038042] generic-usb 0003:04D9:A09F.000A: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.1/input1, status -32
Feb  8 16:37:11 dotmatrix kernel: [10828.309656] usb 1-1.6.3: device not accepting address 24, error -32
Feb  8 16:37:11 dotmatrix kernel: [10828.381760] usb 1-1.6.3: new low-speed USB device number 25 using ehci_hcd
Feb  8 16:37:12 dotmatrix kernel: [10828.788252] usb 1-1.6.3: device not accepting address 25, error -32
Feb  8 16:37:12 dotmatrix kernel: [10828.788575] hub 1-1.6:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 3
Feb  8 16:37:35 dotmatrix kernel: [10851.552743] generic-usb 0003:04D9:A09F.000A: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.1/input1, status -32
Feb  8 16:37:48 dotmatrix kernel: [10864.780978] generic-usb 0003:04D9:A09F.0009: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.1/input0, status -32
Feb  8 16:37:48 dotmatrix kernel: [10864.781857] generic-usb 0003:04D9:A09F.000A: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.1/input1, status -32
Feb  8 16:37:50 dotmatrix kernel: [10867.368090] generic-usb 0003:04D9:A09F.000A: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.1/input1, status -32
Feb  8 16:37:57 dotmatrix kernel: [10874.126293] generic-usb 0003:04D9:A09F.000A: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.1/input1, status -32
Feb  8 16:38:05 dotmatrix kernel: [10882.314361] generic-usb 0003:04D9:A09F.000A: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.1/input1, status -75
Feb  8 16:38:05 dotmatrix kernel: [10882.318341] usb 1-1.6: clear tt 1 (0150) error -71
Feb  8 16:38:05 dotmatrix kernel: [10882.319290] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0008: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input3, status -71
Feb  8 16:38:05 dotmatrix kernel: [10882.322411] generic-usb 0003:04D9:A09F.0009: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.1/input0, status -71
Feb  8 16:38:05 dotmatrix kernel: [10882.323327] usb 1-1.6: clear tt 1 (00a0) error -71
Feb  8 16:38:05 dotmatrix kernel: [10882.327443] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0005: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input0, status -71
Feb  8 16:38:05 dotmatrix kernel: [10882.327450] usb 1-1.6: clear tt 1 (0150) error -71
Feb  8 16:38:05 dotmatrix kernel: [10882.331515] generic-usb 0003:04D9:A09F.000A: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.1/input1, status -71
Feb  8 16:38:05 dotmatrix kernel: [10882.331548] usb 1-1.6: clear tt 1 (00a0) error -71
Feb  8 16:38:05 dotmatrix kernel: [10882.335628] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0006: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input1, status -71
Feb  8 16:38:05 dotmatrix kernel: [10882.335666] usb 1-1.6: clear tt 1 (0150) error -71
Feb  8 16:38:05 dotmatrix kernel: [10882.339740] generic-usb 0003:04D9:A09F.0009: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.1/input0, status -71
Feb  8 16:38:05 dotmatrix kernel: [10882.339777] usb 1-1.6: clear tt 1 (00a0) error -71
Feb  8 16:38:05 dotmatrix kernel: [10882.343846] generic-usb 0003:04D9:0114.0008: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.4/input3, status -71
Feb  8 16:38:05 dotmatrix kernel: [10882.343890] usb 1-1.6: clear tt 1 (0150) error -71
Feb  8 16:38:05 dotmatrix kernel: [10882.347950] generic-usb 0003:04D9:A09F.000A: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6.1/input1, status -71
Feb  8 16:38:05 dotmatrix kernel: [10882.348006] usb 1-1.6: clear tt 1 (00a0) error -71
```

I have found others with the same message, but it always is about a USB TV dongle. Which happens to have the same USB *vendor:device* ID as this reverse-hub. Also, some eight-port hubs (this only have one port) also have the same USB *vendor:device* ID. So I suspect this is the ID of a generic USB interface chip. [lsusb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lspci#lsusb) shows me:

```
05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
```

Where can I get more information about what is happening? How can I make sure it is not a device fault (e.g., if the motherboard is undersupplying current to the devices, would I be able to see it somewhere on the system)?

Why does it list things like this `generic-usb 0003:0C45:7401.0004`? From what I can tell, does it mean `<driver name> <usb bus>:<vendor id>:<device id>:<usb device in bus>`… is correct?

Why does it say `can’t reset device 0000.00`? What do those zeros mean?

Where can I find what status `-32`, `-71`, `-75`, etc. means?

Is there any guide I should be reading? I’m feeling extremely lost on this.

Comment: Jake, thanks also for the link. It is looking like you are right, that will help immensely on solving the immediate issue. And teach me a lesson for buying intel, sigh...

Comment: I start by searching/googling the exact error message (without the date/times/random numbers near the start). Usually points to others with similar problems, sometimes answers too. Not sure what the 0000's mean or the statuses (maybe return/error codes from something else/helper?)

Comment: It would indeed be helpful to have link to what those error codes mean. Looked for it, but so far couldn't find any documentation on it ...

Comment: Yeah, what do those error numbers mean??

Comment: This question is old, but it ranks high on Google. Possibly interesting related news for Ryzen 500-series motherboard users: https://www.anandtech.com/show/16498/amd-usb-connectivity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

USB status codes and possible reasons for them are to be found in your kernel source, in file `Documentation/usb/error-codes.txt`. In [Debian 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_9_(Stretch)) (Stretch), that is contained in package `linux-doc`, which installs it in `/usr/share/doc/linux-doc-4.9/Documentation/usb/error-codes.txt.gz`.

Note that errors in that file are given by their name (like `-71` being `EPROTO`); to find out number/name match you need to:

```
grep -w 71 /usr/include/asm-generic/errno*.h
```

Or for other way around:

```
grep -w EPROTO /usr/include/asm-generic/errno*.h
```

Make sure that development include files are present on the system (in Debian, by doing `apt-get install linux-libc-dev`), or you'll not get any matches...

---

More recent versions (like Debian 11 (Bullseye)) contain `/usr/bin/errno` in `moreutils` package, which allows for easier to remember:

```
% errno 71
EPROTO 71 Protocol error

% errno EPROTO
EPROTO 71 Protocol error
```

Comment: The current location is `Documentation/driver-api/usb/error-codes.rst` due to the kernel documentation project.